# what is wrong with my jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

contents of: file.js

```
var jade;

jade = require('jade');

console.log(jade.render("!!! 5"));
```

on the shell:

```
$ node file.js
```

produces this error:

```
~/Documents/projects/mine/nodetest/jade.js:207
  if (options.cache && !options.filename) {
             ^
```

I am using the latest download of jade,  installed via:

```
$ npm install jade
```

in the root of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jade.render` expects a callback after the template string, which will be passed the results:

```
jade.render('!!! 5', function (err, html) {
    console.log(html); // <!DOCTYPE html>
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/0.27.4/lib/jade.js#L200-220).

Comment: it is taking me a long time to get used to refactoring everything for async